# Anyone know how to allow query string parameters in a wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress

Anyone know how to allow query string parameters in a wordpress page? it's running a muffin theme (betheme)

e.g. localhost/mypage/?name=bill

redirects to the 404 page (but it keeps the url intact).

I want it to not do the redirect and keep the querystring as is.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a htaccess / rewrite thing. WordPress tries to translate `mypage/?name=bill`  or rewrite that into a page or post, and it does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing your permalinks. Navigate to Settings->Permalinks. Then all you have to do is click "Save Changes", and it will reconfigure your permalinks.

[image: Permalinks settings location.]

If that still doesn't fix it, you may have an issue in your Apache or NGINX configuration involving some odd URL rewrite rules. But simply flushing permalinks usually does the trick for any issue involving URLs.